# bash script wont redirect stdout to file

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I am a bash beginner.
I am trying to redirect the output of a bash scipt into a file. Everything but the output of one line is redirected to the file.
This line is creating a file, but writes nothing into it.

```
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 3; sudo kill $cmdpid) & exec sudo hcitool lescan ) > file
```

This isn't working either :

```
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 3; sudo kill $cmdpid) & exec sudo hcitool lescan  > file )
```

When I am executing my bash script the output of the line above will be shown, but when I redirect it to a file it wont.
Please help me.

Comment: Maybe you should also redirect stderr? With `> file 2>&1`

Comment: I tested this already,  the file ist empty. If I start the script without piping the output, I get something like: "LE Scan ... "
. If I pipe the stdout, stderr to the file it will stay empty.

Comment: Why are you using "exec"?  I cannot tell for sure if it is related to your problem or not, but I do not think it is required, and I suggest you remove it to see if your script behaves differently.

Comment: Also, if you need your script to run as root, it may be simpler to `sudo` your script when it is called, instead of each individual command.

Comment: could you provide the output you get without `> file`

Answer (score 0):

When redirecting the standard output try using `1>file` or if you want to append the output to the end of the file `1>>file`